# changed primary email in google account. how to log in?

Tags: support

I added gmail to my google account. Now when i try to log into stack exchange using google it prompts me to create a new account instead of using the existing.

The google account is still the same but google changed the primary email adress.

How can i log in again?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I merged your accounts, but for anyone else who finds themselves in this situation, here are some tips:

- The best solution is to be prepared: [add a second login](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/edit-credentials) to your account *before* changing your email address.
- If you previously set up a Stack Exchange OpenID, you can still log in with your old email address by clicking the "log in using Stack Exchange" button on the login page. Once done, you'll want to [add a second login](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/edit-credentials) with your new email address.
- If you can still *receive emails* at your old address, you can regain access to your account by visiting /users/account-recovery and entering your old address there.
- If, in spite of your best efforts, you've ended up with two accounts... Just follow the instructions here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts