# Multiple accounts for one Google account with multiple emails?

Tags: support, login, user-accounts

Basically, around 2012 I created my current SO account. I have since had an email change, as I became locked out of my yahoo email account, and so I started using the Google email associated with my Google account - the one Google, by default, creates for every Google account holder. I tried to log into Stack Overflow with the google email, and it created a brand new account. At first I was freaked, because I had worked up what (to me) was a decent amount of rep on some sites, and it appeared that somehow my (relatively) inactive account had somehow been pruned from the site.

I eventually discovered that SE creates a new account for each email. Is this intended behaviour when you log on with Google? I was under the impression that it is supposed to be 1 account/Google account.

Comment: did you read this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts and this https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239556/158100 and/or tried https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/edit-credentials.

Comment: @rene I missed the third link. I thought it might be a bug. Eh. Honestly, underneath, it is probably implemented as a simple Dictionary, so I guess it makes sense from a technical point of view, but from a user point of view it seems like an odd feature.

Comment: If you think it is a bug it would need some more clear info / repro steps because I find it hard to understand why you would think that two different emails *wouldn't* lead to two accounts, assuming you didn't link them earlier in any way. And I read your question as *help me fix this situation* not as an *I used a feature that needs to be repaired* but based on the info I think the system behaves as designed.

Comment: @rene I was operating under the assumtion that SE checks for the Google account to log in, not the email address. I was unaware that you had to explicitly link the emails together.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple accounts use in one email is impossible on Google according to me, because your email address is the identity of your Google account and you can create multiple accounts on one email, but you can create multiple accounts on one system or IP address from Google.

Comment: https://www.thegbtech.com/how-to-delete-comment-on-facebook/